# Draft Folder doesn't show messages in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a user logging in to Citrix Server (on Windows 2003) to use Outlook 2007.  In Outlook web access, he sees all his drafts in Draft Folder and can easily access them, but when he is Citrix, he can see the folder, but no messages.

I had him check **Normal** and **Favorite Folders** under **View** -> **Navigation Pane** as well as execute **outlook /cleanviews**  but that didn't help.

Please, help!

Thanks!!!

**EDIT 19.IX.2012 @ 16.45**

I should clarify, we host exchange locally and it syncs with Outlook 2007 in Citrix.  Remote users use either OWA for access or login to Citrix and use Outlook 2007.  In this case ***ALL*** folders appear in Outlook 2007, but draft folder doesn't show any drafts in it, even though OWA shows actual drafts there in the draft folder.

Comment: Can he save a draft in outlook(citrix)?  Does it show up?

Comment: Draft folder shows in Outlook (citrix) with no messages.

Comment: That answer is not specific.  Can he save a draft in outlook?  Yes or no.  Does that draft show up?  Yes or no.

Comment: @Keltari Yes, he can save a draft in Outlook, but they don't show up.  The only thing he sees in Outlook is Draft folder itself.  Now, he can save and edit drafts accessing outlook via web.